# Remove the objects using index value in javascript or react

Tags: javascript

Remove the objects using index value in javascript or react

i have the object list like below. Deleting the object using index value

```
0: {Id: "", value: "aaa" }
1: {Id: "", value: "bbb" }
2: {Id: "", value: "ccc" }
3: {Id: "", value: "ddd" }
4: {Id: "", value: "eee" }
```

deleted object using :

```
   var newArray = delete resultObject[0];
                
                this.setState({ result: resultObject});
             
                 console.log("setState  ",this.state.result);
```

Actual Result
it showing results as

```
[ empty,{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
 
1: {Id: "", value: "bbb" }
2: {Id: "", value: "ccc" }
3: {Id: "", value: "ddd" }
4: {Id: "", value: "eee" }
```

how to make starts from 0, after delete the index 0 .

expected   Result

```
0: {Id: "", value: "bbb" }
1: {Id: "", value: "ccc" }
2: {Id: "", value: "ddd" }
3: {Id: "", value: "eee" }
```

After delete i try to make index starts from 0 not from 1

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let data = [{Id: "", value: "aaa" }, {Id: "", value: "bbb" }, {Id: "", value: "ccc" }, {Id: "", value: "ddd" }, {Id: "", value: "eee" }];

const filterByIndex = (data, index) => data.filter((d, i) => i !== index);

console.log(filterByIndex(data, 0))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all empty values in array with [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let resultsObject = [
    {Id: "", value: "aaa"},
    {Id: "", value: "bbb"},
    {Id: "", value: "ccc"},
    {Id: "", value: "ddd"},
    {Id: "", value: "eee"}
];
delete resultsObject[0];
console.log(resultsObject.filter(function () {
    return true;
}));
```